# HTML как сделать отступ в одну строку без `<br>`

Tags: html, css

Как сделать отступ, не используя `<br>`? Дело в том что `<br>` генерирует символ переноса строки, который выделяется и копируется вместе с текстом, мне же нужно чтобы этого символа не было.

Comment: А что должно быть вместо символа переноса строки? Может CSS отступы попровать?

Comment: Да что угодно, главное чтобы был отступ шириной в одну строку, который 1. Не выделяется при выборе текста 2. Соответствует ширине строки (т.е. если изменить шрифт, чтобы его ширина соответствовала новому шрифту)

Comment: Можно попробовать перехватывать событие копирования и там можете обработать скопированый текст как хотите. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy

Comment: А <p> делает тоже самое? Я чет не в курсе =) Но да, я бы делал через margin/padding.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте что-то подобное:

```
<p class="margin-bottom-20"></p>
```

И css:

```
.margin-bottom-20 {display:block; margin-bottom:20px}
```

Ничего не изменится, т.к. текста нет

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
}

section {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 1.15em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>123</div>
  <br>
  <div>456</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>123</div>
  <div>456</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS тебе в помощь.     `margin-bottom: 20px;`

Comment: Если я изменю размер шрифта такой отступ не изменится вместе с ним.

Answer (score 0):

А почему Вы не хотите использовать родной тег `<p>`? При помощи CSS Вы сможете настроить для него нижний отступ (margin-bottom) по высоте одной строки.

Comment: Как можно через margin-bottom задать отступ в одну строку? Именно не в пикселях подогнать, а чтобы если я поставлю другой шрифт/размер шрифта, оступ был верен?

Comment: @saroff, В таком случае используйте свойство line-height для этой строки со значением, равным удвоенному размеру текущего текста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот можно поиграться CSS

```
.css {
    line-height: 2; //можно в консоли подогнать
}
```

Comment: Распишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователи без проблем могли его понять. Чтобы редактировать ответ, нажмите [edit].